# How to rewrite the url by htaccess and also replace the underscore with dash

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress site running in an apache server, I want to rewrite some the URL in SEO friendly manner, so how to do that

Currently, I have this URL

```
www.example.com/about-us/?id=what_we_do_1
www.example.com/about-us/?id=why_us
```

I want it like

```
www.example.com/about-us/what-we-do-1
www.example.com/about-us/why-us
```

and for this

```
www.example.com/media/?id=team
www.example.com/media/?id=abc_xyz
```

I want something like this

```
www.example.com/media/team
www.example.com/media/abc-xyz
```

my current .htaccess is like the below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: is your site in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

To convert urls like

**/index.php?p=test**

to

**/index.php/test**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(.+)
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /index.php/%1? [R,L]
```

Thus in your case

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(.+)
RewriteRule ^/?about-us?$ /about-us/%1? [R,L]
```

Similarly for other pages

Comment: thanks piyush but it does not work. when i do that it takes me to 404.
And those id like "?id=why_us" is used by jQuery to show hide div

Answer (score 0):

You can try these to convert underscore to dash :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

After that for another url :-

1) www.example.com/about-us/?id=what_we_do_1

htaccess rule will be :-

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/(.*)$ about-us/?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It may help you.

Comment: What is your first rule for?

Comment: is it helpful to you now?

Comment: whatever you passed after about-us it will passed to that page as id.

Comment: is it not ok for you?